# javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

Hi every one i face some problem in Jboss-as-7.1.1.
I properly deploy but when i send the request from client side i am getting error.
I am using Jboss-7.1.1, deployment folder is standalone/deployment (`axis2.war,response.war,SpSpecific.ear,responsecomponet.ear`)

**Deployment log:-**

```
13:00:51,457 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
13:00:52,261 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
13:00:52,381 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
13:00:55,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
13:00:55,288 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
13:00:55,362 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
13:00:55,416 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
13:00:55,521 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
13:00:55,595 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
13:00:55,714 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
13:00:55,780 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
13:00:55,721 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
13:00:55,699 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:00:55,637 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:00:55,951 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
13:00:56,121 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
13:00:56,134 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
13:00:56,236 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
13:00:56,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:00:56,672 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
13:00:57,092 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
13:00:57,940 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Expired Entry Monitor) ARJUNA012210: Unable to use InetAddress.getLocalHost() to resolve address.
13:00:58,202 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
13:00:58,209 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
13:00:58,309 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/vivekray/Desktop/vivek/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments
13:00:58,580 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
13:00:58,676 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "SPAppSpecific.ear"
13:00:58,679 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "response.war"
13:00:58,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "responsecomponent.ear"
13:00:58,685 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "axis2.war"
13:01:00,257 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "SPAppSpecific.jar"
13:01:01,040 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named SPConnectorClient in deployment unit subdeployment "SPAppSpecific.jar" of deployment "SPAppSpecific.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/SPAppSpecific/SPAppSpecific/SPConnectorClient!com.cdac.sp.SPConnectorClientRemote
    java:app/SPAppSpecific/SPConnectorClient!com.cdac.sp.SPConnectorClientRemote
    java:module/SPConnectorClient!com.cdac.sp.SPConnectorClientRemote
    java:jboss/exported/SPAppSpecific/SPAppSpecific/SPConnectorClient!com.cdac.sp.SPConnectorClientRemote
    java:global/SPAppSpecific/SPAppSpecific/SPConnectorClient!com.cdac.sp.SPConnectorClientHome
    java:app/SPAppSpecific/SPConnectorClient!com.cdac.sp.SPConnectorClientHome
    java:module/SPConnectorClient!com.cdac.sp.SPConnectorClientHome
    java:jboss/exported/SPAppSpecific/SPAppSpecific/SPConnectorClient!com.cdac.sp.SPConnectorClientHome

13:01:03,587 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /response
13:01:06,298 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry xpp3.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-run-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,302 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry stax-api.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-run-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,304 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry wstx-asl.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-run-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,307 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jaxws-rt.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-tools-2.1.3.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,311 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jaxb-xjc.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-tools-2.1.3.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,314 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry relaxngDatatype.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-tools-2.1.3.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,323 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry bcel.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,325 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jibx-run.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,332 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry xpp3.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,339 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry stax-api.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,342 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry wstx-asl.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,354 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,358 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,362 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,365 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,370 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,373 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,376 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:06,379 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry serializer.jar in "/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:07,151 WARN  [org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector] (MSC service thread 1-3) Unable to determine dialect of the StAX implementation at jar:file:/home/vivekray/Desktop/vivek/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-modules.jar!/
13:01:07,588 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ClusterBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-3) Clustering has been disabled
13:01:08,140 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.6.1 - file:/home/vivekray/Desktop/vivek/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempdbc1c5c22e866d3/axis2.war-82ac321f1e9789b1/WEB-INF/modules/mex-1.6.1.mar
13:01:08,343 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1 - file:/home/vivekray/Desktop/vivek/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempdbc1c5c22e866d3/axis2.war-82ac321f1e9789b1/WEB-INF/modules/addressing-1.6.1.mar
13:01:08,383 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) Deploying module: ping-1.6.1 - file:/home/vivekray/Desktop/vivek/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempdbc1c5c22e866d3/axis2.war-82ac321f1e9789b1/WEB-INF/modules/ping-1.6.1.mar
13:01:08,434 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.6.1 - file:/home/vivekray/Desktop/vivek/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempdbc1c5c22e866d3/axis2.war-82ac321f1e9789b1/WEB-INF/modules/mtompolicy-1.6.1.mar
13:01:08,460 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.6.1 - file:/home/vivekray/Desktop/vivek/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempdbc1c5c22e866d3/axis2.war-82ac321f1e9789b1/WEB-INF/modules/soapmonitor-1.6.1.mar
13:01:08,489 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) Deploying module: script-1.6.1 - file:/home/vivekray/Desktop/vivek/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempdbc1c5c22e866d3/axis2.war-82ac321f1e9789b1/WEB-INF/modules/scripting-1.6.1.mar
13:01:08,518 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) Deploying module: jaxws-1.6.1 - file:/home/vivekray/Desktop/vivek/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempdbc1c5c22e866d3/axis2.war-82ac321f1e9789b1/WEB-INF/modules/axis2-jaxws-mar-1.6.1.mar
13:01:08,541 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,543 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,549 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,561 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,584 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,586 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,591 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,594 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,605 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry bcel.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,609 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jibx-run.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,615 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xpp3.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,618 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry stax-api.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,626 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry wstx-asl.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,629 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,636 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,638 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry serializer.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,644 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/mail-1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,653 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xpp3.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-run-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,664 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry stax-api.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-run-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,666 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry wstx-asl.jar in "/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-run-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:01:08,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "AsyncResponseComponentVer2.jar"
13:01:09,008 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine] (MSC service thread 1-3) Deploying Web service: version-1.6.1.aar - file:/home/vivekray/Desktop/vivek/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempdbc1c5c22e866d3/axis2.war-82ac321f1e9789b1/WEB-INF/services/version-1.6.1.aar
13:01:09,017 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named SPConnectorResponseComponent in deployment unit subdeployment "AsyncResponseComponentVer2.jar" of deployment "responsecomponent.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/responsecomponent/AsyncResponseComponentVer2/SPConnectorResponseComponent!com.cdac.AsyncSPResponse.SPResponseEJBHome
    java:app/AsyncResponseComponentVer2/SPConnectorResponseComponent!com.cdac.AsyncSPResponse.SPResponseEJBHome
    java:module/SPConnectorResponseComponent!com.cdac.AsyncSPResponse.SPResponseEJBHome
    java:jboss/exported/responsecomponent/AsyncResponseComponentVer2/SPConnectorResponseComponent!com.cdac.AsyncSPResponse.SPResponseEJBHome
    java:global/responsecomponent/AsyncResponseComponentVer2/SPConnectorResponseComponent!com.cdac.AsyncSPResponse.SPResponseEJBRemote
    java:app/AsyncResponseComponentVer2/SPConnectorResponseComponent!com.cdac.AsyncSPResponse.SPResponseEJBRemote
    java:module/SPConnectorResponseComponent!com.cdac.AsyncSPResponse.SPResponseEJBRemote
    java:jboss/exported/responsecomponent/AsyncResponseComponentVer2/SPConnectorResponseComponent!com.cdac.AsyncSPResponse.SPResponseEJBRemote

13:01:10,743 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine] (MSC service thread 1-3) Deploying Web service: SPGenericConnectorVer2.aar - file:/home/vivekray/Desktop/vivek/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempdbc1c5c22e866d3/axis2.war-82ac321f1e9789b1/WEB-INF/services/SPGenericConnectorVer2.aar
13:01:10,784 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /axis2
13:01:10,800 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
13:01:10,802 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 20009ms - Started 323 of 410 services (86 services are passive or on-demand)
13:01:10,981 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "SPAppSpecific.ear"
13:01:10,984 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "response.war"
13:01:10,986 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "responsecomponent.ear"
13:01:10,989 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "axis2.war"
```

**Error Log is:-**

```
13:01:57,692 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) BusinessClass::sendResponse Starts...
13:01:57,712 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.response.war:main" from Service Module Loader
13:01:57,735 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(InitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:64)
13:01:57,737 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:664)
13:01:57,739 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
13:01:57,744 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
13:01:57,746 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
13:01:57,747 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.jsp.response_jsp._jspService(response_jsp.java:116)
13:01:57,749 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
13:01:57,763 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
13:01:57,772 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
13:01:57,774 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
13:01:57,775 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
13:01:57,777 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
13:01:57,778 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
13:01:57,793 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
13:01:57,794 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
13:01:57,808 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
13:01:57,815 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
13:01:57,817 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
13:01:57,822 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
13:01:57,829 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
13:01:57,831 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
13:01:57,832 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
13:01:57,833 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
13:01:57,838 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
13:01:57,839 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**Here  is my Code:-**

```
System.out.println("BusinessClass::sendResponse Starts...");
    HashMap ack_gateway=null;
    try {
        p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                    "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
                    "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        p.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:1099");
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(p);
        System.out.println("Got Initial Context");
        SPResponseEJBHome home = (SPResponseEJBHome)
            PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ctx.lookup
                       "SPConnectorResponseComponent"),SPResponseEJBHome.class);
        //SPResponseEJBHome home = (SPResponseEJBHome) 
              ctx.lookup("SPConnectorResponseComponent");
        System.out.println("BusinessClass::sendResponse Starts...");

        System.out.println("Got Home object");
        SPResponseEJBRemote remote = home.create();
        System.out.println("Got Remote object");

        //process
            System.out.println("Hi 1");
        String targetEndPoint=(String)request.getParameter("targetEndPoint");

        String classid=(String)request.getParameter("classid");

        String corelationid=(String)request.getParameter("corelationid");

        String transactionID=(String)request.getParameter("TransactionID");

        String result=(String)request.getParameter("result");
            Object resxml = null;
        resxml = XmlObject.Factory.parse(result.toString().trim());
            System.out.println("Hi 2");
        CommitResponse commitResponse=new CommitResponse();
        commitResponse.setTargetEndPointURL(targetEndPoint);
        commitResponse.setTransactionId(transactionID);
        commitResponse.setCorrelationId(corelationid);
        commitResponse.setClassId(classid);
        commitResponse.setResponseType(ResponseType.RESPONSE);
        commitResponse.setMessageBody(resxml);
        System.out.println("calling EJB");
        System.out.println("Hi 3");
        ReturnResponse returnResponse = new ReturnResponse();
        returnResponse=remote.makeSubmitResponse(commitResponse);
        System.out.println("Hi 4");
        //STATUS=RESUBMIT
        if (returnResponse.getStatus().equals(RequestStatus.RESUBMIT))
        {
        System.out.println("status: "+returnResponse.getStatus());
        System.out.println("Reason:"+returnResponse.getReason());
        }
        //STATUS=FAILED
        else if (returnResponse.getStatus().equals(RequestStatus.FAILED))
        {
        System.out.println("i am end of exec"+ returnResponse.getStatus());
        String[] erorResponse= returnResponse.getErrors();
        for(int i=0;i<erorResponse.length;i++)
        {
        System.out.println("printing error  :"+erorResponse[i] );
        }
        }

        // Status =SUCESS
        else if (returnResponse.getStatus().equals(RequestStatus.SUCCESS))
        {
        out.println("status    :"+ returnResponse.getStatus());
        out.println("correlationId    :"+ returnResponse.getCorrelationId());
        out.println("TransactionID    :"+ returnResponse.getTransactionId());
        out.println("AuditID   :"+ eturnResponse.getAuditId());         
        }               


} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any one have idea what is the problem please help me.

Thanx

Answer (score 6):

You should use another connecting attributes while preparing InitialContext. There is no jnp in jboss 7.1.1, so you should set property **"java.naming.factory.initial"** to value "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory".

Also property **PROVIDER_URL** should be **"remote://localhost:4447"** (not **"localhost:1099"**) and you should also specify the username and credential (password) in the properties map given to the InitialContext as parameter.

All of the information about which changes to make can be found [**here**](http://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI)

Comment: thankyou for quick reply but when i set the org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory after that i am getting same error ..

Comment: @VivekRai its not enough. There are a couple of things you should do (different in jboss7) to connect. Read entire article (and look for examples):[http://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI](http://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI)